# Adding new records based on date and time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I have a panda dataframe in which it contains two columns sdate and edate. If sdate and edate is not matching then new rows should be added.

Example is,
If `sdate is 17Jan2019:23:56:24` and edate is `18Jan2019:00:02:30`, then it should be splitted into two rows with one row should contain `sdate from 17Jan2019:23:56:24` and `edate as 17Jan2019:12.59:59` and for the second record `sdate should be 18Jan2019:00:00:00` and edate should be `18Jan2019:00:02:30`
Could someone please help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you post a few lines of example data, along with the expected output that would result? That should help others craft a specific solution. By the way, these datetime strings don't look like standard representations to me. It might make life easier if you converted them from strings into datetime objects (using string slicing and `pd.to_datetime`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicating record based on date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54983640/duplicating-record-based-on-date-and-time)